# Symfony 2.8 : one to many relationship

Tags: php, forms, symfony, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have two tables, **Event** and **Product**, one Event has multiple products and one product can be in multiple Events. Here I think it's a **OneToMany** **Unidirectional** relationship. In the form of Event creation I want to have the list of available products in the database and add some products to the event (collection of products).

What's the best way to do that?

---

1. Implement the onetomany or
2. Go in the way to implement ManyToMany and create a third table **EventProducts**

Can anyone help me to choose the best way and how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Implement the onetomany:

In this case you can get the event products list : $event->getProducts

But when you need to access to the event from the product entity via $product->getEvent() !!!!!! this is impossible because the relation is unidirectional

2) Go in the way to implement ManyToMany and create a third table EventProducts :

The solution is this one and create the third entity EventProduct

Hope this can helps

Answer (score 0):

For me logical answer is to use Many-To-Many relationship and crate bridge table, and depending on your needs you can use [bidirectional or unidirectional relationship](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think go and generate EventProduct is a better option so as Event will make oneTomany  relation with EventProduct and Product also will make a relation with EventProduct.So EventPeoduct join Event and Product

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use ManyToMany with `ORM\JoinTable(name="table_name")`

```
class Product {

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Event")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_events")
*/
private $events;

.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to add a third entity instead of doing manytomany it's more maintainable especially when one day you will need to add another fields like (order, creation date ,etc)